# Python - How to assign an encoded one hot vector to a string value

Tags: python, one-hot-encoding

I am not sure whether I am putting my question in a right way. I have encoded POS tags like the following

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

encoder = LabelBinarizer()
transfomed_label = encoder.fit_transform(["CC","CD","DT","EX","FW","IN","JJ","JJR","JJS","LS","MD","NN","NNS","NNP","NNPS","PDT","POS","PRP","PRP$","RB","RBR","RBS","RP","SYM","TO","UH","VB","VBD","VBG","VBN","VBP","VBZ","WDT","WP","WP$","WRB"])
#print(transfomed_label)
#START OF This is to get the mapping between the labels and its index
#print(encoder.classes_)
labels = encoder.classes_
mappings = {}
for index, label in zip(range(len(labels)), labels):
  mappings[label]=index
  #print(mappings)
#END OF This is to get the mapping between the labels and its index


for item in transfomed_label:
    print (item)
```

Now, I have a sentence and I have taken the POS of the sentence

```
import nltk
#nltk.download('punkt')
#nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
examplearray=['This is Timothy learning python']
for item in examplearray:
    tokenized=nltk.word_tokenize(item)
    tagged=nltk.pos_tag(tokenized)
    print(tagged)
```

This gives me `[('This', 'DT'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('Timothy', 'NNP'), ('learning', 'VBG'), ('python', 'NN')]`

I wish this sentence to be encoded as

```
[[000001000],[100000000],[010000000],[000000001],[000100000]]
```

*The above vectors are representative

Can anyone help me in how to make a vector array corresponding to the input sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand you correctly you want something like this:

```
res = [transfomed_label[mappings[tagged[j][1]]] for j in xrange(len(tagged))]
```

Answer (score 0):

First let's get all the pos tags that are in the nltk pacakge. (Beware!! this depends on the penn-tree bank of the language you are using).

```
 pos_tags_list = ['CC', 'CD', 'EX', 'FW', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR', 'JJS', 'LS', 'MD', 'NN', 'NNS','NNP', 'NNPS', 'PDT', 'POS', 'PRP', 'PRP$', 'RB', 'RBR', 'RBS', 'RP', 'TO', 'UH', 'VB', 'VBD', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT', 'WP', 'WP$', 'WRB']
```

Make two mapping dictionaries

```
tag_to_num = {tag: i for i, tag in enumerate(sorted(pos_tags_list))} 
num_to_tag = {i: tag for i, tag in enumerate(sorted(pos_tags_list))}
```

Now, you can extract all the tags from your sentence and use sklearn `one-hot encoder` or pandas `dummies` or keras `to_catgeorical` method to encode your tags.